# Working out a point to spawn a bullet from a ship

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, trigonometry

I'm trying to work out where to spawn a bullet from my 40by40 pixel ship, at the moment the ship is facing north, the nose is 20 pixels away from the centre, so here is my code to try and work it out

```
if( rotate < 0 )
        {
            actRotate = 360 - (rotate * -1) ;
            trace(actRotate);
        }
        else
        {
            actRotate = rotate;
        }
        //var rotateTemp:Number = this.rotation * (180 / Math.PI);
        //this.x = xPos;
        //this.y = yPos;
        _speed_x = Math.sin(rotation*0.0174532925)*7.5;
        _speed_y =- Math.cos(rotation*0.0174532925)*7.5;

        var noseX:Number = xPos + (NoseOfShip * Math.cos(actRotate));
        var noseY:Number = yPos + (NoseOfShip * Math.sin(actRotate));

        this.x = noseX;
        this.y = noseY;
```

Ok so let me just cover somethings, if i rotate my ship to the right by 90 it will give 90 as the value, if i rotate the ship by 180 degrees the value of rotate is -180, if i rotate the ship aniclockwise by 90 it is -90. Now i am really confused on why Flash CS6 does this :(, so I tried to create a convertor above as you can see, if rotate is minus, then just find out what it was ment to be. now this code only works if the ship is -90 (270) degrees.
if the ship is 0,90,-180(180) the bullet is fighted from the nose by to its left by 20 pixels. if someone could give me a hand it would be very helpful, also if you need anymore information please post here

Thank you.

Comment: This is *highly* unclear. Let's get this straight: if `rotate` is -90, then `this` is `(xPos, yPos-NoseOfShip)`, which is what you want, but if `rotate` is 0, then `this` is `(xPos+NoseOfShip, yPos)` which is bad somehow. Is that correct?

Comment: if we were to turn the ship 90 degrees anti-clockwise then the ships rotate variable would be -90, if we rotated the ship 180 degrees clockwise or even anti-clockwise the rotate variable is -180, what I'm trying to do is tell the bullet to spawn at the gun which is in the middle of the 40by40 pixel and at the top of the image, so the position of the gun is at x20 y0 if facing north (0 degrees), if at -90 degrees (270 degrees) the gun would be at y0 x-20, i just need to get the algorithm to work that out using sin and cos

Comment: The issue and required target is not very clear to me. However, it seems like you are disappointed with the angles returned. If so, please check to see if you are using Math.atan2(y, x) to get the angle. It is possible that you are setting the params wrong, ie. providing x first and then y. Such mistake results in the observed angles, as you have described!